# Unable to map postgresql timestamp with timezone in camel jdbc

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-sql

I have following route which get data from postgresql but date object is coming null. it's unable to map that value

My route if following

```
<route id="instrumentqueryshortsell">
        <from uri="direct:restinstumentshortsell"/>
        <bean ref="inConverter" method="convert"/>
        <setBody>
            <simple>select instrumentId as instrument_Id ,amount,easytoborrow as easy_To_Borrow,hardtoborrow as hard_To_Borrow ,datetime as date from instrument_short_sell where instrumentId in (${body}) </simple>
        </setBody>
        <log message="Running following query ${body} " loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>
        <to uri="jdbc:dataSource?useHeadersAsParameters=true&amp;outputClass=<packagename?.InstrumentShortSell" />

    </route>
```

My Pojo class looks like

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class InstrumentShortSell {

    private String instrumentId;
    private long amount;
    private boolean easyToBorrow;
    private boolean hardToBorrow;
    private DateTime date;

    public DateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(DateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getInstrumentId() {
        return instrumentId;
    }
    public void setInstrumentId(String instrumentId) {
        this.instrumentId = instrumentId;
    }
    public long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(long amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public boolean isEasyToBorrow() {
        return easyToBorrow;
    }
    public void setEasyToBorrow(boolean easyToBorrow) {
        this.easyToBorrow = easyToBorrow;
    }
    public boolean isHardToBorrow() {
        return hardToBorrow;
    }
    public void setHardToBorrow(boolean hardToBorrow) {
        this.hardToBorrow = hardToBorrow;
    }


}
```

SQl schema is

```
CREATE TABLE instrument_short_sell (
    instrumentId serial ,
    amount INTEGER,
    easytoborrow boolean,
    hardtoborrow boolean,
    datetime timestamp with time zone
) ;
```

I am unable to map jodadatetime and every time it's coming null. Please help me out how could we map this in camel jdbc

Comment: Did you try to use the **java.lang.Date** instead of **org.joda.time.DateTime**?

Comment: java.lang.Date doesn't have timezone anyway java.lang.Date works perfectly but i need this in Joda datetime

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a type converter for `org.joda.time.DateTime` so Camel can convert the row value to an instance of joda time. Camel does not come with these converters out of the box.

An alternative is to use `java.lang.Object` as the parameter type in your POJO class, and do the type conversion in the setter.

Comment: How could i add type converter would you mind me giving some more details on that and if you have some gthub code that would be really helpful

Comment: See http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html - its also covered in chapter 3 in the Camel in Action 2nd edition book (and also in 1st edition)

Comment: I have added following Type converter but no help as it's not getting picked up. I am using spring based  camel and added bean for this

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException;
import org.apache.camel.support.TypeConverterSupport;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class DateTimeTypeConverter extends TypeConverterSupport {

 @Override
 public <T> T convertTo(Class<T> type, Exchange exchange, Object value) throws TypeConversionException {
  if(type== DateTime.class && value != null){
   
  }
  return (T) DateTime.now();
 }

}

Comment: I used following link as well https://github.com/jankronquist/AirportWeather but no help. I am not sure whether type converter works when we get data from Database